# SpringBoot sample not authenticating

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I am trying to perform a simple inMemoryAuthentication through Spring Boot, but I receive "Invalid username and password." after I submit the login form. At the same time I am unable to see any of the static content on the login screen.

```
package shell;
@SpringBootApplication
public class ShellApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ShellApplication.class, args);           
   }
}



package shell.mvc;
  @Configuration
  public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
    registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
  }
}

package shell.security;

  @Configuration
  @EnableWebMvcSecurity
  public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{   
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/","/home").permitAll()       
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()  
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();

}


@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{

    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");


    }

}

            <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="username"/>
                <input type="password" name="Password"/>
                <button type="submit">Login</button>
           </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the problem, the password name attribute was "Password" with an upper case P instead of "password". The second issue remains with how to allow the login page access to the static content like /images and /css.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing access to the static content on the login page is as follows :

```
      antMatchers("/css/**","/js/**","/fonts/**","/images/**","/","/home").permitAll()
```